# matplotlib savefig() size control

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I wrote a function that took a dataframe generated from Pandas and produce a heatmap:

```
def drawHeatMap(df, city, province, collector, classtype, color, titleposy):
    try:
        thePlot = pl.matshow(df.values, cmap='PuBuGn')
        pl.colorbar(thePlot, orientation='vertical')
        aTitle = (classtype + ' Composition Changes Over Time in ' + city + 
                ', ' + province + '\n' + collector + ' collector. ' + 'rs100')
        pl.title(aTitle, x=0.5, y=titleposy, style='oblique', weight='bold')
        pl.xlabel('Collection Time')
        pl.xticks(range(len(df.columns)), df.columns, rotation=90)
        pl.yticks(range(len(df.index)), df.index)
        fileName = (classtype + '-' + city + '-' 
                + province + '-' + collector + '.png')
        pl.savefig(fileName)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        errorMessage = ('No Data Avaiable for ' + city + ', ' + province + 
                ' with ' + collector + ' collector.')
        print errorMessage
```

The problem I am having is, `savefig()` would save figures with the axis and graphics trimmed. I have to use `show()`, maximize the graph and manually save the figure with the GUI button myself.

How can I fix my function so `savefig()` would save the graphs properly? I tried to put a line like this before `pl.savefig()` to control my figure:

```
       pl.figure(figsize=....)
```

but I end up producing some empty graphs. What is the proper way to write a matplotlib function that give me full control on saving the figure?

**Updated with Example of a problem figure:**
[image]

Answer (score 32):

From the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig), you can add a `dpi` argument to set the resolution.

```
savefig('foo.png', dpi=199)
```

Comment: Updated documentation link: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.savefig

Answer (score 30):

I added    `plt.tight_layout()` before `savefig()`, and it solved the trimming issue I had. Maybe it will help yours as well.

EDIT: I also set the figure size at the begining `matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 40, 12`(you can set your own width and height)

Comment: I had tried using tight_layout() previously but it never worked for me. Including both figsize and tight_layout() is what did the trick for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

**Short:**
You just need to call `pl.figure(figsize=...)` *before* you call the `pl.colorbar` (and all the other stuff)

**Explanation:**
`pl.figure` creates a *new* figure (with given size), on which all `pl.*` methods will act in the following.
So `pl.savefig` just saves the last created figure, which is empty if you created a new one in the preceeding line.

Comment: Calling matshow will create a figure, so he actually needs to call pl.figure() prior to matshow.

Comment: I tried putting pl.figure(...) before pl.colorbar(). It seems to mess up my graph. I think it messed up matshow() somehow

Comment: I moved pl.figure() before matshow. What is interesting is...if I don't use show() and just savefig(). I will have my figures saved (still with stuff trimmed). If I called show() and savefig(). It will show my graphs and bunch of empty graphs

Comment: I put pl.figure() before matshow() Changing the figsize and dpi doesn't do anything to do the saved figure.

Comment: you could try to adjust the margins: with pl.rc('figure.subplot', right=0.9, left=0.15, top=0.95, bottom=0.1)
(and then try to find "good" parameters) or maybe calling pl.tight_layout() just before pl.savefig() can do this automatically.

Answer (score 10):

You need to use the `set_size_inches` function and the `dpi` parameter in `savefig` together to define the saved figure size in pixels.

1. set the figure width and height in inches through `plt.gcf().set_size_inches(10, 5)`.
2. define the `dpi` while saving the figure `plt.savefig('filename.png', dpi=100)`. `dpi` means "dot per inch".
3. The saved figure width will be 1000(10x100) and the height will be 500(5x100). The saved figure size will be 1000x500 in pixels.

Sample code piece:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def fig_size():
    plt.plot(range(0, 10), range(0, 10))
    plt.gcf().set_size_inches(10, 5)
    plt.savefig('charts/fig_size.png', dpi=200)
```

Answer (score 6):

before calling `pl.savefig(fileName)`
do `plt.tight_layout()`

Answer (score 5):

You can pass `bbox_inches='tight'` to the `savefig`

```
plt.savefig("image.png", bbox_inches='tight')
```

It will do the magic.

Answer (score 4):

The command `pl.figure()` makes a new matplotlib figure. The figure size is set at instantiation. You do want to set the figure size, but you already have a figure. So you were on the right track, but try this instead:

```
def drawHeatMap(df, city, province, collector, classtype, color, titleposy):
    try:
        fig = pl.figure(figsize=(....))
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.matshow(df.values, cmap='PuBuGn')
        pl.colorbar()
        aTitle = classtype + ' Composition Changes Over Time in ' + city + ', ' + province + '\n' + collector + ' collector. ' + 'rs100'
        ax.set_title(aTitle, x=0.5, y=titleposy, style='oblique', weight='bold')
        ax.set_xlabel('Collection Time')
        ax.set_xticks(range(len(df.columns)), df.columns, rotation=90)
        ax.set_yticks(range(len(df.index)), df.index)
        fileName = classtype + '-' + city + '-' + province + '-' + collector + '.png'
        fig.savefig(fileName)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        errorMessage = 'No Data Available for ' + city + ', ' + province + ' with ' + collector + ' collector.'
        print errorMessage
```

Comment: I got AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'autoscale_None'

Comment: I changed the code so thePlot=ax.matshow(df.values, cmap='PuBuGn') pl.colorbar(thePlot, orientation='vertical) I got his with ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: The attribute error should not have been caused by my changes to your code. The trace back should provide more information, but it looks like you're trying to access the autoscale_None attribute of some object.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the dpi parameter to set The resolution in dots per inch in savefig method. so you can control the figure size.
for example, if you this code :

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'ser1' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] , 
    'ser2' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
    })

df.plot()
plt.savefig("100.png" , dpi = 100)
plt.savefig("300.png" , dpi = 300)
```

100.png will be :

[100.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B544c.png)

300.png will be :

[300.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZCRr.png)

Comment: Can you show code for that?

Comment: I was add the code

Comment: This method can not set the width and height individually. Try `plt.gcf().set_size_inches(width, height)` together with the `dpi` parameter here. The saved figure width will be width*dpi in pixel.

Answer (score 1):

To save figure on desired size

```
figure = plt.gcf()
figure.set_size_inches(width/100, height/100)
plt.axis('off')
plt.plot(x, y, color='black', linewidth=1)
plt.gca().set_position([0, 0, 1, 1])  
plt.savefig("image.png", dpi=100)
```