# Matplotlib savefig size

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hello I made a graph with Matplotlib in python and as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lixRu.png)
it doesn't display well. I tried solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073045/matplotlib-savefig-size-control) but it change nothing.

```py
# plot
plt.plot('x', 'data', data=df, linestyle='-', marker='o')
buf = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buf, format='png')
buf.seek(0)
```

[As you can see here with plt.show() it's ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljf0l.png)

Comment: Welcome e to StackOverflow, please could you share a sample of the data used to test your code?

Comment: (idk how to upload json file but) https://codeshare.io/G8lNdj