# Savefig saves image at different size than it was given

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib, save

I'm having a prolbme with plt library in python. I try to save a `256x256` image to `512x512` size using savefig. 
When I save the image the dimensions are `394x394`. Where does it comes from?

```
img = np.random.random((256,256))
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(img,interpolation='bilinear',cmap = 'gray')
plt.show()
fig.savefig('test.png',bbox_inches='tight',pad_inches = 0,dpi = 64)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matplotlib savefig() size control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073045/matplotlib-savefig-size-control)

Comment: I think this post may help you: [Specifying and saving a figure with exact size in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714454/specifying-and-saving-a-figure-with-exact-size-in-pixels)