# Wrong image size when using Matplotlib savefig

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, savefig

I use `savefig` from Matplotlib to get an Image from a figure, and this image is modified with PIL after that. I also want to remove every padding.

My problem is that the final size of the image is smaller than expected. For example:

- Size = (8, 10)
- DPI = 300
- We expect a width of 300*8=2400
- But we get a width of 2310

Following this link (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24399985/374458) I've added `plt.tight_layout()` and it works better. But the size is still smaller than expected. I think it's because of the padding which is not 0 before calling `savefig` (pad_inches default seems to be 0.1).

How can a get an image with the right size?

Here is a code sample:

```py
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io

SIZE_X = 8
SIZE_Y = 10
IMAGE_DPI = 300

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(SIZE_X, SIZE_Y), dpi=IMAGE_DPI)
ax.set_axis_off()

ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])

buffer = io.BytesIO()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig(buffer, dpi=IMAGE_DPI, ax=ax, format='png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0, transparent=True)
buffer.seek(0)
image = Image.open(buffer)


print('Expected: ', (SIZE_X * IMAGE_DPI, SIZE_Y * IMAGE_DPI))
print('Figure size: ', (fig.get_figwidth() * fig.get_dpi(), fig.get_figheight() * fig.get_dpi()))
print('Image Size: ', image.size)

plt.close(fig)
del fig
del buffer
```

Output:

```
Expected:  (2400, 3000)
Figure size:  (2400.0, 3000.0)
Image Size:  (2310, 2910)
```

*NB: With the code below I get the right image size but I don't manage to make transparency work.*

```py
image = Image.frombytes("RGBA", fig.canvas.get_width_height(), bytes(fig.canvas.get_renderer().buffer_rgba()))
```

Comment: You should remove `bbox_inches='tight'` from `savefig(...)` if you don't want `savefig` to remove any padding.  Also note that `plt.tight_layout()` has a parameter `pad=` which defaults to `1.08` (measured in fraction of font size).

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution. We ned to set the padding as I suspected, and I thought it wasn't possible. But this works:

```py
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, top=1, bottom=0)
```

Any other solution is very welcome! (making `frombytes` work with transparency maybe?)